# sizeof pointer to structure surprise

Tags: c, pointers, structure, sizeof

```
typedef struct {
  char a[5];
  char b[7];
}footype;

void actOnFooishThings(footype *pfoo){
  printf("Address of pfoo = %d\r\n", pfoo);
  printf("Address of pfoo + 1 = %d\r\n", pfoo + 1);
  printf("Size of pfoo = %d\r\n", sizeof(pfoo));
  return;
}

void main() {
  footype bar;
  printf("Size of bar = %d\r\n", sizeof(bar));
  actOnFooishThings(&bar);
}
```

**output :**

```
Size of bar = 12
Address of pfoo = 537394080
Address of pfoo + 1 = 537394092
Size of pfoo = 4
```

Since adding 1 to pfoo produced the result I expected (12 bytes ahead of base address) I am surprised that sizeof did not result in "12".  I understand the "4". It is telling me the size of a pointer variable but it seems inconsistent with the pfoo + 1 result.
How to I retrieve the size of pointer pfoo?  Do I do something silly like (pfoo + 1) - pfoo?

Comment: Please explain the inconsistency you think this demonstrates.

Comment: Ok, yes I see that I can do "sizeof(footype)" in the function but I still don't understand how it can do the pointer arithmetic correctly but not the sizeof() operation

Comment: Undefined behavior for passing a value of an incorrect type to `printf()`.

Comment: There's not any relationship between a pointer's size and the size of what it is pointing to. Imaging your struct was actually a megabyte in size. Do you think any pointer pointing to that struct must also consume a megabyte of storage?

Comment: @user1160866 Compare `sizeof(pfoo)` to `sizeof(*pfoo)`. That's the difference between `sizeof(footype*)` and `sizeof(footype)`.

Comment: I don't expect the pointer itself to take up that much size but since "ptr +1" results in the understanding that ptr is of a type that takes a megabyte, why wouldn't sizeof() also take that into account?

Comment: `sizeof` tells you the size of its operand in bytes , it doesn't have any complicated logic like "taking things into account"

Comment: dxiv got it right.  Exactly what I was looking for.  I don't know how to nominate your answer as THE answer but I gave you and upvote.  Thank you!

Comment: Sorry but "How to I retrieve the size of pointer pfoo?" is not a clear phrasing for a question about determining the size of what the pointer points to. That is a different question than what you have asked here. I do admire @dxiv however for detecting the question you meant. May I propose to create a separet question on that?

Comment: Reopened (this was briefly closed by someone as "duplicate" of a clearly different question)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the comments are hugely instructive.  Thank you. User Dxiv gave the response I was looking for.
The "correct" syntax for what I was trying to do was:

```
sizeof(*pfoo);
```

or

```
sizeof(footype);
```

Credit to user  Yunnosch  for pointing out my question phrasing was off.  I hope I am forgiven since my knowledge at the time of the post lacked what it now has after asking the question.  The question should have been **"how can I determine the size of the datatype pointed to by pfoo?"**

Comment: Nice idea, to clear out the misunderstandings here by making an answer which explains what you meant in the question and answers it, but NOT change the question away from an existing answer. My respect for that compromise being simpler than making a separate question. I will keep the idea in mind for the future. (To be clear, this is meant honestly, no cynicism or anything intended.)

Comment: I edited my answer after you commented on it.  Is the edit ok?

Comment: It already was a good (in my opinoin upvoteable) answer before. Of course I enjoy the appreciation of my contribution which you express. The answer might have become even better by explicitly explaining about the difference between asked and meant question. I can't upvote again however, sorry. ;-)

Comment: Note: the `()` are not needed in `sizeof(*pfoo);`

Comment: Really?  I have never seen it without the (). It looks cleaner to me with them.

Answer (score 0):

The size of what a pointer points to is irrelevant for the size of the pointer.

In most environments the size of a pointer, as determined by `sizeof(anypointer)` is even always the same in a given environment (usually 4, for some environments 8), independent of what it points to. I.e. the size of a pointer to `int` is the same as a pointer to `char` and as a pointer to your struct type.
What a pointer points to is irrelevant for the size of the pointer itself.
Your `pfoo` is a pointer.
Your `bar` is not, it is a variable of the struct type `footype`, its size is 12.

By the way, as comments have pointed out, you are using the wrong format specifier for printing, that is however irrelevant for your size experiments.

As M.M has pointed out, pointers being always of the same size in a given environment is not theoretically strict, though applicable to most current systems. Compilers are allowed to have different sized pointers to different types.
I consider out of scope for this discussion of pointer sizes to plain data the observed differences between sizes of pointers to functions and ponters to objects, as mentioned by chux.

The point is, the size of what a pointer points to is irrelevant for the size of the pointer.

Comment: I didn't know that, is just theory or there are real cases?

Comment: "or there are real cases?" I see it often enough in 2021 with a pointer size difference between a pointer to a function and a pointer to an object.

Comment: just wanted to add a couple of comments addressing what Yunnosch answered. First, yes I understand the size of pointer variables.  It's not what I was asking about.  dxiv answered my question by mentioning sizeof(*pfoo)  would work as I expected.  That aside yes I know my printf statements are not great.  I was just trying to write pseudo code to not distract from my main question.  Thanks everyone!